# Grant Remote Access to a User

Tags: mysql

I've made a user only for specific operations make, read, update and delete (*CRUD operations*) on a specific database like so:

```sql
REVOKE ALL PREVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'username'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

But then, I'm getting this error message trying to access the database remotely with the previous user:

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'ip_address' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Any idea how to grant the remote access without giving it all previleges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the hostname of a user to `localhost`, MySQL will not accept remote connections for the user. You need to set the host name to an ip address or ip address range. To allow connections from anywhere, execute

```
RENAME USER 'username'@'localhost' TO 'username'@'%';
```

Please also have a look at the official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html